# Start next paragraph on this line

Tags: formatting, paragraphs, resume

**TL;DR**:
Can I convince LaTeX to start the next paragraph on the same line as the current one?

---

The format I’ve chosen for my résumé looks something like this:

> **EXPERIENCE**
>
> **Doctor Midos, Inc.                                                January–June 1988**
>   *Midos Machine Operator* :
>       Connected the sanafratz to the grepsling and
>       hypercharged the whizding.
>       Checked for loose wires in the kugelator.
>   *K'fitsas Haderech Machine Pilot* :
>       Blew a giant bubble-gum bubble
>       by ingenious use of a laser gun.
>       Staged daring rescue on Space Station Doomstein.

The code I’ve developed looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Short (i.e., one- to two-line) items
\newcommand*{\ritem}{\par}

% Short item with inline header
\newcommand*{\rnote}[1]{\par\textit{#1}:}

% Job title, to be followed by an \ritem-list of accomplishments, responsibilities, etc.
\newcommand*{\rposition}[1]{%
    \renewcommand*{\ritem}{\relax\renewcommand*{\ritem}{\par}}%
    \rnote{#1}%
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\begin{document}
\section{Experience}

\textbf{Doctor Midos, Inc.} \hfill \textbf{January--June 1988}
    \rposition{Midos Machine Operator}
        \ritem  Connected the sanafratz to the grepsling and
                hypercharged the whizding.
        \ritem  Checked for loose wires in the kugelator.

    \rposition{K'fitsas Haderech Machine Pilot}
        \ritem  Blew a giant bubble-gum bubble
                by ingenious use of a laser gun.
        \ritem  Staged rescue on Space Station Doomstein.
\end{document}
```

As in the formatted example, the first `\ritem` starts on the same line as the position description, since the expansion of the macro is `\relax`; the second (and subsequent ones) will begin on new lines since the first invocation has redefined itself to `\par`.

The part where `\ritem` is redefined to redefine itself feels kinda icky, and I’m hoping to be able to get rid of it. But that requires that the `\rposition` macro somehow indicate that the next paragraph should begin on the same line as itself—is that possible?

Comment: Why not remove the second \ritem?

Comment: @dustin, because the actual code is a bit more complicated; there are two different amounts of vertical space depending on whether it's an `\ritem` or an `\rlistitem`.

Comment: … and because I don’t actually have the blank lines in the source that the question showed; edited to fix.

Comment: @Jon, I’m using `\ritem` to list distinct aspects of a job. The format I’ve chosen puts the first item on the same line as the job title; every subsequent item begins its own line. In other words, every `\ritem` *does* visually and semantically start its own paragraph—except the first one is displayed differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use conditionals.  Here's a some (re)definitions using `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\providebool{nopar}
\renewcommand{\rposition}[1]{%
  \rnote{#1}%
  % set 'nopar' = true
  \booltrue{nopar}}

\renewcommand{\ritem}{%
  \ifbool{nopar}%
    % if nopar = true, do nothing except set 'nopar' false
    {\boolfalse{nopar}}%
    % if nopar = false, start a new paragraph and keep 'nopar' (redundantly) false 
    {\par\boolfalse{nopar}}%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can peek ahead and see whether there is an `\ritem` following an `\rposition` (using `\@ifnextchar`). If this is the case, just gobble it (using `\@gobble`). Of course, if it will *always* be followed by an`\ritem`, you can just gobble it regardless. Here's a way using the first (conditional) approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Short (i.e., one- to two-line) items
\newcommand*{\ritem}{\par}

\makeatletter
% Short item with inline header
\newcommand*{\rnote}[1]{\par\textit{#1}:\@ifnextchar\ritem{\space\@gobble}\relax}
\makeatother

% Job title, to be followed by an \ritem-list of accomplishments, responsibilities, etc.
\newcommand*{\rposition}[1]{%
    \rnote{#1}%
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\begin{document}

\section{Experience}

\textbf{Doctor Midos, Inc.} \hfill \textbf{January--June 1988}
    \rposition{Midos Machine Operator}
        \ritem  Connected the sanafratz to the grepsling and
                hypercharged the whizding.
        \ritem  Checked for loose wires in the kugelator.

    \rposition{K'fitsas Haderech Machine Pilot}
        \ritem  Blew a giant bubble-gum bubble
                by ingenious use of a laser gun.
        \ritem  Staged rescue on Space Station Doomstein.

\end{document}
```